# jquery removeClass doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

While `firstli.hasClass('selected')` does work and retrieves the correct element. The removeClass function doesn't seem to remove to the class. When an element is unchecked I would like the first `li` to be unchecked as well.

Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eC8hF/29/) (the code is at the bottom)

**Note: I want "Select All" to become unchecked when you uncheck one of the other options.**

```
var firstli = $('.dropdown-menu.inner li').first();
firstli.click(function(event) {   
    if (!firstli.hasClass('selected')) {    
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('selectAll');       
    }
    else {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
    }
    return false;
});

var alllis = $('.dropdown-menu.inner li:not(:first-child)');

alllis.click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {    
        alert(firstli.hasClass('selected')); //true
        firstli.removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have looked at the jsfiddle, and it seems to work at my machine (firefox) what browser did you use?

Comment: yeah its working on my chrome too

Comment: It's not working for me using Chrome. He wants "Select All" to become unchecked when you uncheck one of the other options.

Comment: If you put another alert after .removeClass look at what happens to the list items - the 'selected' class gets removed as expected but gets added again immediately after. Some other part of your code is adding that class back in

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie Lol I just saw this too!

Comment: It's removed and added in setSelected then

Comment: Thank you @WillemEllis you are right, it does not work! it is somewhere in the bootstrap lib i think

Comment: @Ayrad you should add Willem Ellis comment in your question too - that makes the question more clear

Comment: added Willem Ellis' comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `setSelected()` rechecking the Select All option. To fix this, I changed that function to the following:

```
setSelected: function (c, d) {
    if (d) {
        this.$menu.find("li").eq(c).addClass("selected")
    } else {
        this.$menu.find("li").eq(c).removeClass("selected")
        this.$menu.find("li:first-child").removeClass("selected")
    }
}
```

Basically, if it has to remove the `selected` class, you know they're not all checked. This works.

http://jsfiddle.net/eC8hF/30/

Comment: +1 for being the `first one` to actually get the question correctly and then solving it as well